# kendo Bar chart x axis labels overlapping

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using kendo bar chart in my application, the x axis values/labels are overlapping. How can i avoid overlapping?

I have used rotation to fix this issue, but is there any other approach?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [xAxis.labels.step](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-xAxis.labels.step) to have it only print every-other label.

Comment: Thanks this helped me tonight.